# How can I specify the validity of a certificate in an OpenSSL configuration file?

Tags: openssl, x509

I am fairly new to OpenSSL and I am trying to specify a certificate that is valid for just one hour using OpenSSL. I have been successful in doing so with `openssl ca` using the `-startdate` and `-enddate` options, but I was wondering if it is possible to set the validity in a configuration file for use with `openssl req`? If so, could you provide an example?

I tried using similar syntax as:

`privateKeyUsagePeriod = ASN1:SEQUENCE:privateKeyUsagePeriod`

`[privateKeyUsagePeriod]`

`notBefore = IMPLICIT:0,GENERALIZEDTIME:20170501000000Z`

`notAfter = IMPLICIT:0,GENERALIZEDTIME:22910501000000Z`

This syntax does not seem to work for the validity. Thank you all in advance for any guidance you can give me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your example for PrivateKeyUsagePeriod is wrong; notAfter should be tagged 1 not 0. Although since practically no software ever looks at PKUP, this error may not matter.

More substantively, PKUP is an extension and X509v3 extensions use an OID+varying structure that requires OpenSSL to allow essentially any ASN.1 type in order to support future additions without code change. Validity is part of the fixed part (from v1) and is implemented by specific code, and is not the same type anyway (not tagged, not OPTIONAL, and CHOICE{UTCTime,GeneralizedTime}).

For `openssl ca` you can use `default_startdate` and `default_enddate` in the config file section named by `default_ca` (not the one named by `x509_extensions`) instead of the commandline options. See the man page on your system [or on the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/ca.html) under 'CONFIGURATION FILE OPTIONS'.

For other commandline operations there is currently no code supporting this; you can either write your own app(s) calling the library, or since OpenSSL is opensource just make a copy and modify it.